# Django migration doesn't always work

Tags: python, django, migrate

Ok So I have some migration issue in django 1.8 and I need to work around by manually  dropping my DB table  every time.

My problem is following - every time after I change my table by adding new fields and running

```
python manage.py makemigrations 

python manage.py migrate
```

it says no changes to apply. (migrate folder is empty)

(It is not picking up changes I made in model file )

At the end table stays with old structure and it gives me errors when I test.

If I drop table in DB directly  and start again it works but it is annoying since I have to recreate a test data every time.

Is it a bug in migration or just me ?

For example this is my table from models file but it happened before with other tables.

```
@with_author 
class BOM(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    product= models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    material =  models.OneToOneField(Material, related_name = 'material')
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    materialuom = models.CharField(max_length=1,
                              choices=UOM_CHOICES)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=10)
    waste =  models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True,max_digits=19, decimal_places=10)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % ( self.id, self.name)
```

Comment: Could the problem be with the `with_author` decorator you are using?

Comment: did you try: `python manage.py makemigrations appname`?

Comment: @ahmed I tried with app name and it picked it up , but it created a mess since table already exist from when I dropped it and it recreated it without writing anything in django migrate terminal. My impression it is bug in migration.

Comment: had to drop all the tables of the app to solve it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I got my work around thanks to comment from @ahmed.
Every time when doing  `python manage.py makemigrations appname` it is mandatory to type the appname .Without the appname functionality is not always working.

However I believe there is still problem in django1.8 migrate process.